# Where can I find resources for PHP implementation of linked list data structure?

Tags: php, data-structures, linked-list

my question is what I have set on the title nothing to post here.

Comment: A linkED list is a data structure, not an algorithm. Several algorithms can be applied to a linked list in order to provide various operations, including traversing a linked list, inserting new nodes, etc. So, despite what you say, there's certainly *some* information you could have added in order to improve the quality of your question.

Comment: oh... thanks for the correction bobby anyway I find the answer already. :)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You must also strive to attain a good communication skill to foster your stackoverflow experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [SPL](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php): this provides [linked lists](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/class.spldoublylinkedlist.php) for PHP, together with other data structures such as heaps, stacks and queues

Comment: thanks @MarkBaker the link is really helpful though the content I have provided is not that useful for it's title just really got lazy of what to post next on the question body and it's a little bored to be too serious when trying to figure out something that is difficult to resolve ;)